# Как отсортировать массив? Сначала латиница, потом кириллица, потом цифры

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

К примеру есть массив:

```
arr = ['б', 'D', 7, 'U', 'Ш', 9, 5, 'J']
```

А мне нужно отсортировать его по алфавиту, и привести к такому:

```
sort === ['D', 'J', 'U', 'б', 'Ш', 5, 7, 9];
```

Делаю так, но кириллица и цифры взваливают вперёд:

```
   let sort = arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a._id.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b._id.toLowerCase())
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю еще один вариант:

```js
let arr = ['б', 'D', 7, 'U', 'Ш', 9, 5, 'J'];

// если попалось число прибавим к нему 2000, иначе вернем код символа
// коды английского алфавита находятся до 1000, кириллица после 1000, 
// а числа мы двигаем в диапазон 2000+
let c = a => 10 > a ? 2e4 + +a : a.charCodeAt(0);
arr.sort((a, b) => c(a) - c(b));

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: хороший вариант, только нужно, наверное, при таком подходе перед получением кода буквы приводить её в нижний или верхний регистр, т.к. коды верхнего регистра идут раньше и сейчас получается сначала идет `Ш`, а потом `б`

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич я думал об этом, однако автор не указал желаемого порядка сортировки внутри группы, по-этому не стал усложнять

Comment: там же в вопросе есть "нужный порядок") - `sort === ['D', 'J', 'U', 'б', 'Ш', 5, 7, 9];`

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич мда, видимо сказываются ночные посиделки, сейчас подкручу тогда =), жаль там нет цифры записанной строкой и строчной английской буквы

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич даже плюс Вам забыл поставить +)

Answer (score 8):

для сравнения букв в зависимости от языка можно использовать `Intl.Collator` с указанием нужной локали, в данном случае `en`, что бы латинские буквы были раньше кириллицы. Но цифры всё равно будут первыми, поэтому нужно на каждой итерации проверить варианты, когда один из аргументов число, а второй нет

- когда `a` НЕчисло и `b` число возвращаем -1, чтобы значения не менялись местами
- когда `a` число и `b` НЕчисло возвращаем 1, чтобы буква была раньше цифры
- в остальных случаях, когда оба параметра число или оба НЕчисло используем `collator`, чтобы отсортировать буквы и цифры между собой

так же у `Intl.Collator` есть опция `caseFirst`, которая указывает символы какого регистра должны идти раньше

```js
const arr = ['б', 'D', 7, 'U', 'Ш', 9, 5, 'J']

const collator = new Intl.Collator('en');

const sortArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if(isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)){
    return -1
  }else if(!isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)){
    return 1
  }
  return collator.compare(a, b);
});
        
console.log(sortArr);
```

Comment: eslint рекомендует использовать Number.isNaN. я использовал гибрид этой и своей конструкции.