# javascript: сортировка слов по возрастанию сначала начинающие с русских букв, затем с латинских

Tags: javascript, строки, сортировка

подскажите, есть ли быстрый (простой, встроенный) способ отсортировать массив строк по возрастанию, но так чтобы сначала шли слова, которые начинаются с русских букв, а затем - с латинских

обычные строки сортируются стандартно:

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

а вот требуемый вид сортировки как делать?

в голову пока приходит решение в лоб - смотреть, входит ли первая буква строки (после удаления пробелов и т.п. пустых символов) в русский алфавит (т.е. проверять по массиву из 33-66 букв)

может как-то можно сделать более просто?

Comment: Где-то с месяц назад был подобный вопрос. Не могу найти...

Comment: Может помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971330/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, спасибо за ссылку - взял оттуда `const collator = new Intl.Collator('ru');` это конечно какая-то магия (впервые просто встречаю), но работает

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, вообще странно конечно, у народа обратная проблема - может быть просто браузер почему то думает что стандартная локаль не русская

Comment: @Zhihar стандартная локаль и коллатор я связи конечно же не вижу. Это разные классы и дефалт у каждого свой. Но рад что помог.

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, просто непонятно почему у других пользователя обратная ситуация :)

Answer (score 1):

Подготовил пример для наглядности.

```js
const array = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Андрей', 'Garry', 'Anton', 'Karl', 'Bob', 'Jonny'];

const ruCollator = new Intl.Collator('ru-RU');
const sortRu = [...array].sort((a, b) => ruCollator.compare(a, b));

const enCollator = new Intl.Collator('en-US');
const sortEn = [...array].sort((a, b) => enCollator.compare(a, b));

console.log(sortRu);
console.log(sortEn);
```

Comment: да, тоже одинаковый

Comment: @Zhihar array.sort сортирует на мете